# The error is keep going!!(can't assign to operator)

Tags: python

Acutally I am making a program to find an area of a trapezoid..
My code is

```
print("This program will help you to find the area of a trapezoid")
height = input("Tell me the height")
upper_line = input(" Tell me the length of upper line")
bottom_line = input(" Tell ne the length of bottom line")
upper_line + bottom_line = line
line*height/2 = area
print("The area of trapezoid is",area)
```

And there is an error in line5(can't assign to operator)
Please help me

Comment: You are trying to assign to an operator in line 5. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the content before and after the "=" sign on lines 5 and 6.

Generally speaking, when you assign a calculated value (such as 1 + 2) to a variable (let's call it "foo"), it would be

```
foo = 1 + 2
```

with the variable "foo" on the left side of the "="

However, if you switch the order to

```
1 + 2 = foo
```

you will get this error.

Unlike in mathematics, where using an equals sign is understood as a declaration of things being equivalent, when assigning variables in python (and computer languages in general), order matters.

Answer (score 0):

Make line 5 `line = upper_line + bottom_line`.  You'll have the same problem with line 6.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading a basic Python programming tutorial (such as the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html)). Particularly, you need to study assignment statements. But as a quick reference: assignment (using the `=` sign) works like this:

1. Calculate the answer of the right-hand side (evaluation)
2. Assign the answer of #1 to the variable name on the left-hand side (assignment)

If the left-hand side isn't a single variable name, this process fails, and you get an error. (In more advanced usage, you can assign to multiple variables at once using tuples, but it's different to the way you're doing it, and you won't need to learn it right now.)